# Vitest in-source testing: Property 'vitest' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'

Tags: vitest

I'm trying the [in-source testing](https://vitest.dev/guide/in-source.html) of vitest. Here is the example given by the doc:

```js
if (import.meta.vitest) {
  const { it, expect } = import.meta.vitest;
  it('add', () => {
    expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
  });
}
```

But I get the red squiggles `Property 'vitest' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'` in VSCode. How can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```json
// tsconfig.json 
{"compilerOptions": {"types": ["vitest/importMeta"]}}
```

You can see the doc https://vitest.dev/guide/in-source.html#typescript

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer. Please can you explain why/how it works? Try to avoid answers that depend heavily on links, and include your reasoning as part of the text of your answer